# Can't hear caller after updated from 4.3 to KitKat 4.4.2 on Moto G

Tags: calls, 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

I have a retail Motorola Moto G 16 GB with 4.3.

After updating to KitKat 4.4.2 (using the official Motorola process), I can't hear the caller's voice. But when activating the speakers or using a headphone I can hear the other side. Prior updating there where no problems at all.

I also did a full factory-reset, which did not helped.

With this issue the phone is practically unusable, I appreciate any help.

Comment: We had [some similar issues](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=call+hear+is%3Aquestion) already asked for, which you might wish to check – though most of them have it the other way round (other side can't hear them).

Comment: @Izzy None of them was related to an android update, nor Moto G, nor the issue described here (not hearing the caller). Read thru all of them, no result.

Comment: If I had found an exact match, I'd pointed out :) Was hoping they might give a clue, though. Sorry to read they didn't. // As you're still using "official firmware", and unless you get a better answer, I'd say contact Moto service. If a factory-reset didn't solve it, it must be the system (or hardware), so with some luck, they might send you a replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this issue, I exchanged the device at the vendor (same model), upgraded to Kitkat, and everything seems to work fine. Sorry for not having a more technical answer, I would love to have one, but in the end I needed a phone that works.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [ayush's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/69823/16575), Motorola customer care advises to wipe the cache to solve the issue, and it reportedly worked.

As ayush omitted the steps required to follow whis advice, here are the steps to do "Wipe the cache partition". This will remove any temporary files that may be causing the problem, but will not delete your files or settings.

1. With the phone powered off, press the <kbd>VOL DOWN</kbd> KEY for 2-3 seconds, then <kbd>POWER</kbd> key, then release.
2. The device will display different BOOT OPTIONS
3. Use the <kbd>VOL DOWN</kbd> Key to SCROLL to Recovery and <kbd>VOL UP</kbd> Key to select

   > Tip: If the device reboots, you may have waited to long to make a selection, you will need to begin the process again.
4. The device will display the Motorola logo and then the Android in distress (logo with Exclamation mark)
5. Press and hold the <kbd>VOL UP</kbd> key for 10-15 seconds. While still holding the <kbd>VOL UP</kbd> key tap and release the <kbd>POWER</kbd> key

   > Tip: You can try this step, holding the phone in landscape. If you are stuck on step 6, try a force reboot by pressing the <kbd>POWER</kbd> key and <kbd>VOL DOWN</kbd> key, and start the process again.
6. The device will display additional menu options (Text will appear in BLUE)
7. Use the <kbd>VOL DOWN</kbd> Key to scroll to wipe cache partition and the <kbd>POWER</kbd> Key to select this option
8. The device will then perform the partition wipe
9. The device will reboot and start the normal power up sequence

Comment: This solved my problem temporarily, a factory reset solved the problem when I call, I hear everything, but the problem persists when I receive a call. I found a suggestion that during the call, the system mistakenly redirects the sound to the headphones, so plugging in headphones would make you hear the caller. Unplugging them resets the audio stream to default phones. Seems I would carry a pair of phones with me now.. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Motorola is working on a fix for this issue. See the [forums](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/48fb0b8150?page=19) on their site.

> Following KitKat upgrade, devices appear to show any of the following symptoms:
>
> 1. lose mobile signal
> 2. display 'No Sim' icons,
> 3. fall into Aeroplane mode (while not displaying Aeroplane Icon status)
> 4. Mobile signal can often be recovered by swapping into and out of Aeroplane mode.
> 5. Pop-up errors about being in Aeroplane mode while attempting to make calls during signal problems.
> 6. Aeroplane mode observed in about phone status (while no aeroplane mode shown on icons)
>    7.Popup errors - the process "com.android.phone" has stopped
> 7. Not specific to individual SIM cards - multiple SIMs (cutdown/original confirmed as impacted)
> 8. Suggestion that it only occurs with mobile data enabled - to be investigated.
> 9. The release notes also mention your low volume issue.

Apparently the patch is ready and the release notes have also been confirmed. This is just a matter of time. People should not update to KitKat 4.4.2 on Moto G until above mentioned patch is available.

*Note: I am NOT a moto employee, I am just a fellow user like you, who now tells others to beware before updating the phone to KitKat.*

Answer (score 1):

I am using Moto g (16GB comes with kitkat) for last 3 three week. And last night for the first time when i was calling then there were no sound at all. Seems there was no voice transmission. Then i rebooted and it worked but after some time same thing happened and continue to happened frequently . Then i did factory reset and now it works well. it has been passed 1 day and no issue. I think its a software problem. I goggled a bit about this issue and found a post which states the same issue and occurred after 3 week of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola customer care told me to "wipe the cache partition"  and it is now working fine. Follow the steps below to [wipe the cache partition](https://motorola-mobility-en-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/100135/p/30,6720,9151/reg/2581748).

> **Lollipop Steps:**
>
> 1. With the phone powered off, press and hold the Volume Down button and
>    the Power button at the same time until the device turns on. You will
>    see the word "Start" with an arrow around it.
> 2. Press the Volume Down
>    button twice to highlight "Recovery mode".
> 3. Press the Volume Up button
>    to restart into Recovery mode. You'll see an image of an Android robot
>    with a red exclamation mark and the words "No command."
> 4. While holding
>    down the Power button, press the Volume Up button.
> 5. Use the volume
>    buttons to scroll to "wipe cache partition" and press the Power button
>    to select it.
> 6. "Reboot system now" will be highlighted, press the Power
>    button to select it.
>
> **KitKat Steps:**
>
> This will remove any temporary files that may be causing the problem,
> but will not delete your files or settings.
>
> 1. With the phone powered off, press the VOL DOWN KEY for 2-3 seconds then POWER key then release.
> 2. The device will display different BOOT OPTIONS
> 3. Use the VOL DOWN Key to SCROLL to Recovery and VOL UP Key to select
>
> *Tip: If the device reboots, you may have waited to long to make a
> selection, you will need to begin the process again.*
>
> 4. The device will display the Motorola logo and then the Android in distress ( logo with Exclamation mark)
> 5. Press and hold the VOL UP key for 10-15 seconds. While still holding the VOL UP key tap and release the POWER key
>
> *Tip: You can try this step, holding the phone in landscape. If you are
> stuck on step 6, try a force reboot by pressing the Power key and Vol
> Down key, and start the process again.*
>
> 6. The device will display additional menu options (Text will appear in BLUE)
> 7. Use the VOL DOWN Key to scroll to wipe cache partition and the POWER Key to select this option
> 8. The device will then perform the partition wipe
> 9. The device will reboot and start the normal power up sequence

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, ayush! Maybe you want to [edit] your answer and include the steps required to "wipe the cache partition"? That would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: Edited the answer to provide the steps for wiping the cache partition form the motorola website.